# My wordpress website has a little has two buttons on the top right

Tags: wordpress

I just finished setting up my Wordpress website. My website is being run locally and is behind Nginx proxy manager. I don't have any plugins activated at all, but for some reason when I access my website through my domain. I get these icons on the top right:

[image]

When I access my website through the local ip address it is not there at all. I was thinking that maybe the problem is the Site address and maybe I should change it to my domain name.

Comment: Can you attach the full image of top right section?

Comment: @MuneebShoukat My website is like this now